# Entity Framework 5 Data mapping

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have mapped a complex type to the results of a SP, and am getting the following error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'CLMModel.GetContractPerformanceReview_Result'. A member of the type,
>   'LastYearProfit', does not have a corresponding column in the data
>   reader with the same name.

I know that this normally indicates something wrong in the mapped types, so I have looked and tweaked them to no avail. The incoming type is a `decimal(18, 2)` (on SQL Server), and the mapped type is also `decimal(18, 2)`. I have tried increasing the precision to `38,2` without success, as I thought it may be a case of a potentially larger values being detected.

The value is generated from a column, with this definition, so I can see no reason that it would not map successfully.

I have even tried `Create a new Complex Type`, to use a generated type, but it still fails. I have confirmed that the field names match too.

Ad assistance would be much appreciated. I have tried searching for this on SO, without success, but if there is another question you can point me to, please do. Thank you.

Comment: Obvious question - does the stored procedure return a column called `LastYearProfit`?

Comment: @Richard - yes. I have checked and double checked, the names match. This was occurring on another column previously, which has changed, I believe, because I removed and readded it, so putting it down the order. I also have other calls form the same DB with similar mappings that are working OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have found the cause of this, which is that the Stored Procedure that generates this response created different results sets depending on the parameters. This meant that when I ran it manually, it showed the columns, but the entity framework could not correctly identify the correct columns.

So the lesson is - if your SP returns different results for different parameters, make sure that they all return the same columns.